# CUDA disabled problems on Windows

Tags: windows, cuda

I have previously had CUDA running successfully on 2 PCs, but after extensive use (a couple of hours of computations) it becomes disabled. All CUDA applications (eg TechpowerUp GPU-Z) say that Cuda is not installed (cuda tickbox is empty on this app, similar result on others). The same happens on both PCs.

If I reboot the PC, the problem will often (not always) rectify itself.

I've tried re-intsalling CUDA drivers (5.5 and 5.0), but the same thing always happens.

It seems very strange that I see this happening consistently on both PCs, yet can't find any references on the internet to other people experiencing the same.

Any help/ideas would be appreciated.

UDPATE:
it has been suggested I run nvidia-smi. Results are:

> C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI>nvidia-smi
>   Wed Oct 02 14:16:35 2013
>    +------------------------------------------------------+
>   | NVIDIA-SMI 5.320.57   Driver Version: 320.57         |
>   |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
>   | GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
>   | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
>   |===============================+======================+======================|
>   |   0  GeForce GTS 240    WDDM  | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
>   | 56%   70C  N/A     N/A /  N/A |      997MB /   998MB |     N/A      Default |
>   +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
>   +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>   | Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
>   |  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
>   |=============================================================================|
>   |    0            Not Supported                                               |
>   +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the cause here, it was quite unexpected.

I use Remote Desktop to communicate between my PCs. Apparently this takes over the graphics driver on the host machine and disables CUDA. I will try using something like VNC instead.

Comment: In view of the answer, your post was was really misleading.

Comment: Remote Desktop wasn't even mentioned, while it changes everything.

Comment: that's the point, I had absolutely no idea it would make any difference. If I had, I wouldn't have needed to ask the question. I also didn't mention everything else I do on this PC, like surf the web, email etc because I didn't think they were relevant either.

Comment: it seems I'm no longer having this problem since upgrading to Windows 10 - is this expected?

Comment: Are you sure? I use RDP too and I'm having the same problem too on Windows 10 x64. I have 2x 980Ti, but `gpu1` (the second gpu) have its CUDA deactivated and couldn't be accessed in Theano. So I only have `gpu0` (the main GPU, which also connects to the monitor) available. But the `gpu1` load is 0% in CPU-Z, so I'm not sure if it's locked by RDP.

Comment: I'm not sure - I observed that once, but I always use VNC anyhow, not RDP.

Comment: As I understand, this problem with RDP has been fixed in later versions of the CUDA Toolkit.